# Host asp.net core app in IIS to access from other PC's inside the network

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, deployment, host

How can i host my Asp.Net Core (1, 2 or 2.1) web app in Windows IIS to be able to access it from other PC's in our local network (or my Virtual OS)? My PC is a Desktop Windows 10 Pro (not Win Server).

I have followed the [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) article, but i can't get it to work.

What i did based on that article is as following:

Ensure Prequisites: Visual Studio 2017, Install Asp.Net Core 2.1 SDK, Add Internet Information Services (IIS) from `Turn Windows features on or off`, Asp.Net [Core Hosting Bundle](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.1.1-windows-hosting-bundle-installer) Installer [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.1.1) (verified AspNetCoreModule module in IIS) and then:

Publish a default asp.net core app in Visual Studio (Build > Publish > Folder) to a folder and copy its contents to `D:\publish1`.

in IIS, right-click Sites > Add Website... and use these values (according to the picture shown [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#create-the-iis-site)):

```
  [Site name]: mysite_com
  [Physical path]: `D:\publish1`
  [IP address]: `All Unassigned`
  [Port]: 80
  [Host name]: mysite.com
```

Also change `Application Pools > mysite_com > Basic Settings > .Net CLR Version` to `No Managed Code`.

Now, my web app can't be reached in browser when i tested `http://[IP of my PC]/mysite.com` or similar addresses.

So, What's wrong with these IIS settings?

**Edit:** It seems that this is not specific to .net core 2.1 only (the instruction is mainly the same when you change the .net core version of article), so i modified the title and question.

Comment: Change [IP address]: `All Unassigned to your machine Ip Address may fix this issue. also, ensure that port: 80 is not in use by another application

Comment: `http://[IP of my PC]/example.com` will not work instead you should try `http://example.com`. Are you trying to test with an actual domain name bound to your IIS website or just a dummy domain?

Comment: @MostafaEsmaeili that dosn't change the issue.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I want my colleagues be able to see the app i developed. `http://example.com` will not work as this is not a world wide website, it is a web app hosted from my PC in a local network. I'm sure the users need to specify my machine name or IP to specify where is the files hosted on the network

Comment: @S.Serp you will then need to host your .NET Core App as an application under `Default Website` and then your colleagues will be able to access website using your PC and then application alias e.g. {IP}/mysite.com

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Thanks, i didn't check that yet but is it possible to Add New Website for it as suggested in most cases?

Comment: The key here is to truly understand the site binding you set on IIS, as that determines from another machine what URL you can use. https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run the diagnostics tool and learn the report.

Comment: @S.Serp The easiest solution in your scenario is to host under Default Website as an application as per my knowledge

Comment: @MohsinMehmood i found how to do that, please take a look at the answer

Comment: @LexLi thanks, i downloaded your app (Jexus Manager) but it doesn't run in my PC (nothing happen when i run its exe). Anyway, i found what was wrong in my settings (port number and host name) as posted below

Comment: @S.Serp looks good. In your question you asked about setting up app to be accessible at `http://[IP of my PC]/mysite.com` which require application to be added under Default website. However, you can setup different websites to be accessible at different ports e.g. `http://[IP of my PC]:890`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution and want to record it here as it may be helpful for other ones. Its interesting that the Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) does not explain all details for such a common scenario as when you want to run you web app in an intranet network like as building of a large office. Here is the required IIS settings:

1. Ensure you have IIS (Turn windows features on or off > internet information services)
2. Ensure Asp.Net Core Host Bundle is installed: dotnet-hosting-2.1.1.exe: AspNetCoreModule in IIS can be verified from IIS Manager > Web Sites > any website eg Default Website > Modules.
3. Publish your asp.net core app in Visual Studio (Build > Publish > Folder) to a folder and then copy its generated files to other desired destination path (eg D:\publish1) to avoid file lock issues for next code updates.
4. in IIS, choose Application Pools (from the left tree view above the Sites), right-click > choose Add Application Pool > Name: myAppPool, .Net CLR Version: No Managed Code. (for .Net Core Apps)
5. Find your IP address: run `ipconfig` in the command prompt (in windows 10, it is under Ethernet adapter: `IPv4 Address`, eg: 192.168.103.xyz).

Now, there are two options: A) Add Website, or, B) Add Application inside Default Website

**A) Add Website** => `http://192.168.103.xyz:890`

in IIS Manager, choose "Sites" node from the left tree view > right-click > Add Website... >

```
[Site name]: myApp
[Application Pool]: Select:myAppPool as specified in step 4. if you didn't create it in before, IIS will add a new pool based on your SiteName which you can edit its Basic Settings later in Application Pools tree view node to set its .Net CLR Version to No Managed Code. 

[Physical path]: path to your published files (eg: D:\publish1)

[IP address]: can change it to your IP (from drop down) or left it to `All Unassigned`

![Port]: must be something other than 80! (eg: 890), it must be a free port not taken by other apps. you can test different values if some fails. in my case, port 4, 100, 200, 1100 works; but 80, 110 (pop3 email) or 3000 not works as they are used/reserved for other means.

![Host name]: left it blank if you want to access this app from your network! It is required for real internet world wide web sites!
```

[image]

- The key settings you may miss here is the **Port (other than 80)** and **Host name (empty string)** as noted above! Check [this link](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers) to know about different port numbers: System Ports (0-1023), User Ports (1024-49151), Dynamic/Private Ports not assigned usually (49152-65535).
- You can set more than 1 port number or IP for your site: choose [Bindings] from the right panel and edit or add the entries.
- Allow your chosen port number through your **Firewall** to be able to access it from external PC's. For windows firewall go to: `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Inbound Rules > New rule > [Port] option`, specify your port number > ...
- browse: 192.168.103.xyz:890 (using your ip address and choosen port number). If you don't set specific IP for your site (ie `All Unassigned`) then you can also browse localhost:890 to see your app.

**B) Add Application** (inside Default WebSite) => http://192.168.103.xyz/myApp

- in IIS Manager, choose "Default Web Site" from the left tree view, right click > Add Application > choose a name for [Alias]: (eg: myApp), [Application Pool]: Select:myAppPool as specified in step 4, [Physical path]: your publish path (eg: D:\publish1)
- browse: localhost/myApp in a browser in your own PC to test if you see your web application.
- browse: 192.168.103.xyz/myApp (using your IP address) if you want to get it from other PC's on the network or a virtual PC.

Comment: However, your settings is not for "such a common scenario". A typical setup for internal web sites, should use a proper host name and port 80 (different from what you chose), and then proper DNS records can be added, so everyone can access it from their machines. Opening ports on Windows Firewall should also be common sense. Besides, .NET Core SDK does not install the Host Bundle (that's why there are tons of 500.19 reported over the internet).

Comment: @LexLi thanks for comment. at least, this setting make it possible that other ones on our office can access to my web app. I can't find a way to use port 80 with a host name to work in our local network and this is why i asked it here. if you know how to do it, can you share it here please?

Comment: You don’t even have a configurable DNS server in the office/company?

Comment: @LexLi unfortunately, i don't have access to the IT dept.

Comment: Thanks for your information definitely has fix my issue