# How to share asp.net core application on local network using ubuntu?

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222220/host-asp-net-core-app-in-iis-to-access-from-other-pcs-inside-the-network) I want to share my asp.net core application with other devices on the same network but, the thing is I'm running linux (ubuntu 20), using mssql as database (maybe this would help, too) and actually, I don't know how to do the same thing using linux.

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Comment: It did! Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you host the asp.net core application on Linux,  the most easily way is using the asp.net core build-in kerstrel server.  You could set your asp.net core application to use specific port like below:

```
   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseUrls("http://*:5003");
                });
```

Then you could follow below steps to publish the application to linux server and use `http://<serveraddress>:5003` to access the application.

1. In your development computer to run `dotnet publish --configuration Release` to generate asp.net core application

2.Copy the ASP.NET Core app to the server using a tool that integrates into the organization's workflow (for example, SCP, SFTP). It's common to locate web apps under the var directory (for example, var/www/helloapp).

3.From the command line, run the app: dotnet <app_assembly>.dll.

4.use `http://<serveraddress>:5003` to access the application.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1#publish-and-copy-over-the-app).

Comment: Can't I just access to the application without publishing it?

Comment: How you run your application without publishing?  If you could run the application by using VS code or else. Then you could access the application with the right port like 5000.